# Python split for lists

Tags: python, list

If we have a `list` of `strings` in python and want to create sublists based on some special `string` how should we do?

For instance:

```
l = ["data","more data","","data 2","more data 2","danger","","date3","lll"]
p = split_special(l,"")
```

would generate:

```
p = [["data","more data"],["data 2","more data 2","danger"],["date3","lll"]]
```

Comment: Why the functional programming tag?

Comment: to get an answer using functional programming methods of python

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is one approach (as it often is):

```
>>> l = ["data","more data","","data 2","more data 2","danger","","date3","lll"]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> groupby(l, lambda x: x == "")
<itertools.groupby object at 0x9ce06bc>
>>> [list(group) for k, group in groupby(l, lambda x: x == "") if not k]
[['data', 'more data'], ['data 2', 'more data 2', 'danger'], ['date3', 'lll']]
```

We can even cheat a little because of this particular case:

```
>>> [list(group) for k, group in groupby(l, bool) if k]
[['data', 'more data'], ['data 2', 'more data 2', 'danger'], ['date3', 'lll']]
```

Comment: nice cheat! for the lambda, it can be improved like `lambda x: not x` or just `operator.not_`

Answer (score 5):

One possible implementation using itertools

```
>>> l
['data', 'more data', '', 'data 2', 'more data 2', 'danger', '', 'date3', 'lll']
>>> it_l = iter(l)
>>> from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile
>>> [[e] + list(takewhile(lambda e: e != "", it_l)) for e in it_l if e != ""]
[['data', 'more data'], ['data 2', 'more data 2', 'danger'], ['date3', 'lll']]
```

---

*Note**

This is as fast as using groupby

```
>>> stmt_dsm = """
[list(group) for k, group in groupby(l, lambda x: x == "") if not k]
"""
>>> stmt_ab = """
it_l = iter(l)
[[e] + list(takewhile(lambda e: e != "", it_l)) for e in it_l if e != ""]
"""
>>> t_ab = timeit.Timer(stmt = stmt_ab, setup = "from __main__ import l, dropwhile, takewhile")
>>> t_dsm = timeit.Timer(stmt = stmt_dsm, setup = "from __main__ import l, groupby")
>>> t_ab.timeit(100000)
1.6863486541265047
>>> t_dsm.timeit(100000)
1.5298066765462863
>>> t_ab.timeit(100000)
1.735611326163962
>>>
```

Comment: Why are you including the purely-for-example `groupby(l, lambda x: x ="")` line?  It does nothing.  Moreover, `[list(group) for k, group in groupby(l, bool) if k]` should be 10%+ faster.

Comment: @DSM: I had erroneously added it, but removing it is not much of a distance. Btw, as you mentioned, in similar ways, `[list(takewhile(bool, it_l)) for e in it_l if e != ""]` should also be equally faster, but I still feel, the difference is negligible and comparable.

Answer (score 2):

[`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce) comes to mind:

```
def split(iterable, where):
    def splitter(acc, item, where=where):
        if item == where:
            acc.append([])
        else:
            acc[-1].append(item)
        return acc
    return reduce(splitter, iterable, [[]])


data = ["data","more data","","data 2","more data 2","danger","","date3","lll"]
print split(data, '')
```

Result:

```
[['data', 'more data'], ['data 2', 'more data 2', 'danger'], ['date3', 'lll']]
```

Comment: One thing to note is that `reduce` in python is actually `foldl` in CS terms - the CS `reduce` must be used on a function that does not care in what order the inputs come in.  This can get you into trouble if you try to `reduce` in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure wether this is the most "pythonic" way of solving it.

```
def split_seq(seq, sep):
    start = 0
    while start < len(seq):
        try:
           stop = start + seq[start:].index(sep)
           yield seq[start:stop]
           start = stop + 1
        except ValueError:
           yield seq[start:]
           break

ll = ["data","more data","","data 2","more data 2","danger","","date3","lll"]
p = [i for i in split_seq(ll,"")]
```

Comment: +1: This is probably the fastest. Btw instead of LC you could have simple done `list(split_seq(ll,"")`

Answer (score 1):

Heres one idea. :)

```
def spec_split(seq,sep):
    # Ideally this separator will never be in your list
    odd_sep = "!@#$%^&*()"

    # Join all the items with the odd separator and split
    # anywhere the odd separator + separator + odd seperator meet
    # This makes a list of items broken by the separator
    jumble = odd_sep.join(seq).split(odd_sep+sep+odd_sep)

    # split the remaining items broken by odd separators into sublists
    return [item.split(odd_sep) for item in jumble]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
def split_special(x, on):
    try:
        ix = x.index(on)
    except ValueError:
        return [x]
    return [x[:ix], *split_special(x[(ix + 1):], on=on)]
```

Edge cases, e.g. when `on` is not present in `x`, or when it appears as first or last element, are not handled well by this solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
    lst = ["data","more data","","data 2","more data 2","danger","","date3","lll"]
    join_list = ",".join(lst)
    split_list = join_list.split(",,")
    result = [i.split() for i in split_list]
    #result =[['data,more', 'data'], ['data', '2,more', 'data', '2,danger'],  ['date3,lll']]
```

Comment: This is not at all the result that the topikstarter wanted.