# split list by certain repeated index value

Tags: python, list, indexing, split, element

I have a list of integers, in which some are consecutive numbers.

What I have:

`myIntList = [21,22,23,24,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` etc...

What I want:

```
MyNewIntList = [[21,22,23,24],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
```

I want to be able to split this list by the element 0, i.e when looping, if the element is 0, to split the list into separate lists.
Then, after splitting `myIntList` whatever number of times (based on the recurrences of finding the element 0), I want to append each 'split' or group of consecutive integers into a list within a list.

Also would I be able to do the same sort of thing with a 'list of strings' instead of integers?  (Split the main string list into smaller lists based on a reoccurring element)

EDIT:

How would I go about splitting the list by consecutive numbers?  There's a part in my list where it jumps from 322 to 51, there is no 0 in between.  I want to split:

```
[[...319,320,321,322,51,52,53...]]
```

into

```
[[...319,320,321,322],[51,52,53...]]
```

basically, how do I split elements in a list by consecutive numbers?

Posted here:
[Split list of lists (integers) by consecutive order into separate lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277467/split-list-of-integers-by-consecutive-order-into-separate-lists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
it  = iter(myIntList)
out = [[next(it)]]
for ele in it:
    if ele != 0:
        out[-1].append(ele)
    else:
        out.append([ele])

print(out)
```

Or in a function:

```
def split_at(i, l):
    it = iter(l)
    out = [next(it)]
    for ele in it:
        if ele != i:
            out.append(ele)
        else:
            yield out
            out = [ele]
    yield out
```

It will catch if you have a `0` at the start:

```
In [89]: list(split_at(0, myIntList))
Out[89]: [[21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]

In [90]: myIntList = [0,21, 22, 23, 24, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [91]: list(split_at(0, myIntList))
Out[91]: [[0, 21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out @PadraicCunningham.  I find definitions helpful.

Answer (score 3):

(I vaguely suspect I've done this before but I can't find it now.)

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate

def itergroup(seq, val):
    it = iter(seq)    
    grouped = groupby(accumulate(x==val for x in seq))
    return [[next(it) for c in g] for k,g in grouped]
```

gives

```
>>> itergroup([21,22,23,24,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 0)
[[21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
>>> itergroup([0,1,2,0,3,4], 0)
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 4]]
>>> itergroup([0,0], 0)
[[0], [0]]
```

(That said, in practice I use the `yield` version of the same loop/branch that everyone else does, but I'll post the above for variety.)

Comment: Thanks @DSM.  Variety in coding is always useful.  :)

Comment: for some reason I get an ImportError: cannot import name accumulate...Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, I changed Python 2 to 3, and it worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing:

```
myIntList = [21,22,23,24,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
myNewIntList = []
lastIndex = 0
for i in range(len(myIntList)):
    if myIntList[i] == 0:
        myNewIntList.append(myIntList[lastIndex:i])
        lastIndex = i

myNewIntList.append(myIntList[lastIndex:])
print(myNewIntList)
# [[21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

You can split strings using the `str.split` function:

```
s = 'stackoverflow'
s.split('o') # ['stack', 'verfl', 'w'] (removes the 'o's)

import re
[part for part in re.split('(o[^o]*)', s) if part] # ['stack', 'overfl', 'ow'] (keeps the 'o's)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myIntList = [21,22,23,24,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

new = []
m,j=0,0
for i in range(myIntList.count(0)+1):
    try:
        j= j+myIntList[j:].index(0)
        if m==j:
           j= j+myIntList[j+1:].index(0)+1



        new.append(myIntList[m:j])
        m,j=j,m+j
    except:
        new.append(myIntList[m:])
        break
print new
```

**output**

```
 [[21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

**output2**

```
myIntList = [0,21,22,23,24,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

[[0, 21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: try `[0,21,22,23,24,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the whole list, appending to a temp list till `0` is found. Then you again reset the temp list and continue.

```
>>> myIntList = [21,22,23,24,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> newlist = [] 
>>> templist = []
>>> for i in myIntList:
...      if i==0:
...          newlist.append(templist)
...          templist = []
...      templist.append(i)
... 
>>> newlist.append(templist)
>>> newlist
[[21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

and for strings you can use the same approach by using the `list` call

```
>>> s = "winterbash"
>>> list(s)
['w', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'b', 'a', 's', 'h']
```

Also using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> myIntList = [21,22,23,24,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> temp=[list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(myIntList,lambda x:x== 0) if not k]
>>> if myIntList[0]!=0:
...     newlist = [temp[0]] + [[0]+i for i in temp[1:]]
... else:
...     newlist = [[0]+i for i in temp]
... 
>>> newlist
[[21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Thank you kindly.  Very interesting technique. I was following something along the lines of this recipe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529523/python-split-for-lists
the first response helped me, but I just wanted to see at least one other approach.

Comment: @MikeIssa Added. Is it what you want?

Comment: @BhargavRao: what if 0 is the first element?  (On your itertools version.)

Comment: @DSM Yep. Did not see that edge case. I will change it soon. Thanks

Comment: @DSM, Any thoughts how to make it work using the itertools version?

Comment: @DSM I did it trivially. Please mention if there is any other better way.

Comment: @BhargavRao, you should use a generator expression for the first,  you can call `next(gen)` to get the first element

Comment: @Padraic Guess that'll make it similar to your answer. I'll edit it anyway.

Comment: @BhargavRao, I mean the groupby solution, then you wont be storing multiple copies of the data

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, will edit in a few seconds.

Comment: @ BhargavRao Thank you for going the extra mile and showing the itertools method.  I was stuck because I couldn't get the 0 in my list initially, but you cleared things up exceptionally well.  Kudos!

Comment: @MikeIssa DSM has added a better approach. Do follow his answer. Thanks

Comment: New post, if anyone can help.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277467/split-list-of-integers-by-consecutive-order-into-separate-lists

Answer (score -3):

You could try:

```
i = 0
j = 0
loop = True
newList = []

while loop:
    try:
        i = myIntList.index(0, j)
        newList.append(myIntList[j:i])
        j = i + 1
    except ValueError as e:
        newList.append(myIntList[j:])
        loop = False

print newList
[[21, 22, 23, 24], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```