# split a list to several nested lists based on "2 consecutive" entries

Tags: python, list

My question is semi-answered in 
[Python split for lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529523/python-split-for-lists) page. However, I need to split based on TWO consecutive components (not one component). And the code is in Python.
For example:

```
list = ["id","title","data","more data","id","title","data 2","more data 2","danger","id","title","date3","lll"]
```

and I want the following outcome:

```
new_list = [["id","title","data","more data"],["id","title","data 2","more data 2","danger"],["id","title","date3","lll"]]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Danger:** Don't use **built-in** function as variable names. `list` is built-in funtion in python.

Try this,

```
>>> list1 = ["id","title","data","more data","id","title","data 2","more data 2","danger","id","title","date3","lll"]
>>> new_list = []
>>> new_list_ = []
>>> for l in list1:
        if list1[0]==l:
            if new_list_:
                new_list.append(new_list_)
            new_list_ = []
        new_list_.append(l)
        if list1.index(l)==len(list1)-1:
            new_list.append(new_list_)
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> new_list
[['id', 'title', 'data', 'more data'], ['id', 'title', 'data 2', 'more data 2', 'danger'], ['id', 'title', 'date3', 'lll']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this in segments. First off, find all the indexes of `'id'` where the following item is `'title'`

```py
lst = ["id","title","data","more data","id","title","data 2","more data 2","danger","id","title","date3","lll"]
lst_len = len(lst)
indexes = [i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v=='id' and i+1 < lst_len and lst[i+1]=='title']
```

Then iterate over them as pairs and split appropriately.

```py
import itertools

# from itertools recipes
def pairwise(iterable, fillvalue=None):
    a, b = iter(iterable), iter(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=fillvalue)

result = [lst[i:j] for i,j in pairwise(indexes)]
```

```py
>>> result
[['id', 'title', 'data', 'more data'], ['id', 'title', 'data 2', 'more data 2', 'danger'], ['id', 'title', 'date3', 'lll']]
```

---

You could use that pairwise iterator to more quickly find the indexes, too.

```py
indexes = [i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(pairwise(lst)) if a=='id' and b=='title']
```

Comment: This is kind of a fun problem in Haskell too. [Here's a sample solution](https://repl.it/repls/NarrowInfantileSorting)