# Split a list in python with an element as the delimiter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split, delimiter

I want to create sub-lists from a list which has many repeating elements, ie.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Wherever the `'a'` begins the list should be split. (preferably removing `'a'` but not a must)

As such:

```
l = [ ['b', 'c', 'c', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'b'] ]
```

I have tried `new_list = [x.split('a')[-1] for x in l]` but I am not getting the desired "New list" effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python split for lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529523/python-split-for-lists)

Comment: Thank you @AMC, I'll give that a whirl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write,

```
new_list = [x.split('a')[-1] for x in l]
```

you are essentially performing,

```
result = []
for elem in l:
   result.append(elem.split('a')[-1])
```

That is, you're splitting each string contained in `l` on the letter `'a'`, and collecting the last element of each of the strings into the result.

Here's one possible implementation of the mechanic you're looking for:

```
def extract_parts(my_list, delim):
    # Locate the indices of all instances of ``delim`` in ``my_list``
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == delim]

    # Collect each end-exclusive sublist bounded by each pair indices
    sublists = []
    for i in range(len(indices)-1):
        part = my_list[indices[i]+1:indices[i+1]]
        sublists.append(part)
    return sublists
```

Using this function, we have

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']
>>> extract_parts(l, 'a') 
[['b', 'c', 'c', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip and enumerate to do that. Create a list of ids for separation and just break it at those points.

```
size = len(l)
id_list = [id + 1 for id, val in
        enumerate(test_list) if val == 'a']


result = [l[i:j] for i, j in zip([0] + id_list, id_list +
    ([size] if id_list[-1] != size else []))]
```

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to shadow buitlins (e.g. `id`) with global variables. Also, what is `test_list`? Is it supposed to be the same as `l`?

Comment: @Brian, yes you are right, I just quickly put up something and I apologize, I will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: Even after correcting the misnamed variable mentioned above, this approach does not produce the output that the OP expects. Using the OP's example input produces `[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['b', 'c', 'b', 'a']]`

Comment: @Brian The OP said not a must, therefore I did that

Answer (score 2):

It will not include the delimiter

```
import itertools
lst =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']
delimiter  = lst[0]

li=[list(value) for key,value in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda e: e == delimiter) if not key]

print(li)
```

Explanation: **groupby** function will create a new group each time key will change

```
 Key     value
True     itertools._grouper object pointing to group 'a'
False    itertools._grouper object pointing to group 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b'
True     itertools._grouper object pointing to group 'a'
False    itertools._grouper object pointing to group 'b', 'c', 'b' 
True     itertools._grouper object pointing to group 'a'
```

In if condition checking if the key is false, return the **itertools._grouper object** and then pass **itertool object** to list.

Answer (score 1):

Create a counters array for each element you want to split at then write a condition in this fashion:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']
counters = [0,0,0]                                #to count instances
index = 0                                         #index of l
startIndex = 0                                    #where to start split
endIndex = 0                                      #where to end split
splitLists = []                                   #container for splits
for element in l:
    if element == 'a':                            #find 'a'
        counters[0] += 1                          #increase counter
        if counters[0] == 1:                      #if first instance
            startIndex = index + 1                      #start split after
    if counters[0] == 2:
        endIndex = index                         #if second instance
        splitList = l[startIndex:endIndex]           #end split here
        counters[0] = 1                              #make second starting location
        startIndex = index + 1
        splitLists.append(splitList)                 #append to main list of lists
    index += 1
print(splitLists)
```

So basically you are finding the start and end index of the matching pattern within the list. You use these to split the list, and append this list into a main list of lists (2d list).